# Get multiple table output from Stored Procedure Mysql (Laravel + SPA)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, vue.js

I have a **stored procedure** that returns me **three tables** (3 Selected)
in **Laravel** when a call the procedure

```
Public function getTables(Request $request){
  $output =DB::select('call all_result(?,?)', array($request->in1,$request->in2));
  return response()->json($output);
}
```

**Result: return only first table, i need 3 tables together**

**Update:**

Stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure all_result()
BEGIN

select * from table1;
select * from table2;
select * from table3;

END
$$
```

---

**Note:**

I use **SPA(Single Page Application)Vue Js frontend** and i use **Laravel backend**

**VueJs** call **API** from **Laravel Via Axios**

My Database is **MYSQL**

Answer (score 1):

Write code in a stored procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PRECEDURE all_result()
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM table1;
SELECT * FROM table2;
SELECT * FROM table2;

END
$$
```

Comment: This code is close to the code I put in the question